How to connect Kafka Connect Debezium Postgres connector a third-party Kafka cluster?
We have a Kafka Connect cluster running several plugins and connectors. One of them is Debezium Connector for Postgres v2.5, which takes rows from tables in the database and writes them to kafka topics.
There is a need to connect a third-party Kafka cluster to our Kafka Connect so that another team can view work and results(topics) of our Debezium Postgres connectors (they don't have a configured Kafka connect cluster).
How can this be done? From a third-party Kafka cluster there is only the bootstrap server address (e.g. example1.kafka.connect.com:9092) with SASL/OAUTHBEARER authentication.

I believe you've asked this before? Did you try MirrorMaker2? https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#georeplication

Yes, it was me. I'm not sure if this is what I need. I just need to view messages, without any mirroring

Kafka Connect can link to third-party Kafka, but connecting Kafka Connect doesn't wouldn't anyone to view topics. That'd just be a consumer process.

How can I configure Kafka Connect link to a third-party Kafka cluster? I'd try it, and if it's not what I need, I'd configure MirrorMaker2

Same way you configured Debezium. You set the bootstrap servers in connect-distributed.properties file

but if there is a different authorization and authentication method in a third-party kafka cluster, do I need to make a separate worker for this?

That's correct. Could you edit your question to include more details about this?

I've edited my question
